# Counting objects in array to change progress bar with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some sample data like so:

```
var data = {
    "section": {
        "1": {
            "question": [{
                "id": "1a",
                "num": "1",
                "title": "test"
            }, {
                "id": "1b",
                "num": "2",
                "title": "test"
            }]
        },
        "2": {
            "question": [{
                "id": "2a",
                "num": "1",
                "title": "test"
            }, {
                "id": "2b",
                "num": "2",
                "title": "test"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Using this I'm attempting to count the number of questions. So for this sample of data that would be 4 questions in total...

The plan is to update a progress meter width using this data:

```
<div id="progress"><div id="bar"></div></div>
```

Here is the JS code I have started putting together:

```
var number = 0, numQuestions, total, width;

function updateProgress() {

    number += 1;

    numQuestions = data.question;

    //total =

    width = total / number;

    $('#progress #bar').animate({'width':width});

}
```

To get the `width` I'm guessing that I'd need to add BOTH sections and questions together and divide it by the width of the progress bar and then set the width of the progress as the number of that number??

Can anyone give some help and point me in the right direction?

The main issues are:

- numQuestions is returning undefined, so obviously I'm doing it wrong
- I'm not sure how to work out the total... should this be the `#progress #bar` width calculated against the numQuestions? Or something else entirely?

Comment: `data.question` will be undefined.

Comment: Yes I know. I have stated this as one of the issues!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend modifying your data structure as follows:

```
var data = {
    "sections": [ // sections is now an array instead of an object
        {
            "question": [{
                "id": "1a",
                "num": "1",
                "title": "test"
            }, {
                "id": "1b",
                "num": "2",
                "title": "test"
            }]
        },
        {
            "question": [{
                "id": "2a",
                "num": "1",
                "title": "test"
            }, {
                "id": "2b",
                "num": "2",
                "title": "test"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Unless you need to name the sections, there is no need to key them.

You can then grab the number of sections like so:

`var numSections = data.sections.length;`

To get the total number of questions in all sections, you'll need to create a loop:

```
var numQuestions = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.sections.length; i++){
    var questions = data.sections[i].question;
    for (var j = 0; j < questions.length; j++){
        numQuestions++;
    }
}
```

Then, to update the progress bar you would:

```
function updateProgress() {
    number++;
    width = number / numQuestions * 100;
    $('#progress #bar').animate({'width':width + '%'});
}
```

You'll want `#progress` to have a set width, and `#bar` to have a percentage based width ranging from `0` to `100%`.

If you need to name the sections, you can count the number of questions like so:

```
var numQuestions = 0;
for (var sect in data.section){
    var questions = data.section[sect].question;
    for (var j = 0; j < questions.length; j++){
        numQuestions++;
    }
}
```

You can see all of this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/wAGHS/1/

Comment: I do need to name the sections :)

Comment: Thanks I have been able to build upon what you have posted :)

Answer (score 1):

## Answer to counting questions

If you look at your `data` object, there is no `data.question`. The questions are under `section` and then under `1` or `2` (`data.section.1.question` and `data.section.2.question`).

So, start out with setting a `var` to `data.sections`. [Loop through](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500531/600101) the sections and [check the size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6700/600101) of the question object beneath and sum them up to a variable. Then you have the total number of questions.

Now to the next part: You have the total of four questions. What should the progress show? The number of questions answered by the user or what?

Comment: The number increments every time that function is fired (which is when a user views a question). So basically that function will fire 4 times in this particular example.

Comment: Allright. But then you do not need to recalcuate the number of questions, correct? Move that to another function at startup. Then the width in percent should be `(number/total)*100` since if they have seen 0 questions 0/4 = 0 and 1/4 = 0.25 (25%) so on.

Answer (score 1):

In your `object` `data.question` is `undefined`, as each one of properties of `section` object has a `question` property you can count them.

```
var number = 0;
for (key in data.section) {
   number++
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KuJgN/

Answer (score 1):

In your updateProgress(), since the data object has no element at key 'question'

```
data.question
```

will return undefined.

Assuming:
    section must be an object and
    question must be an array

And further assuming data can contain multiple 'sections', to get the total number of questions in data, try:

```
var total_questions=0;
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(k){
    Object.keys(data[k]).forEach(function(num){
        total_questions+=data[k][num]['question'] 
            ? data[k][num]['question'].length 
            : 0;
    })
});
```

If data only ever contains one section, the above can be simplified to:

```
var total_questions=0;
Object.keys(data.section).forEach(function(num){
    total_questions+=data.section[num]['question'] 
        ? data.section[num]['question'].length 
        : 0
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This function does count your "questions" in your data object:

```
function countquestions(obj) {
   var count = 0;
   for(var prop in obj) {
       if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
           for(var propp in obj[prop]) {
               if (obj[prop].hasOwnProperty(propp)){
                   ++count;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   return count;
}
```

it returns 2 for your data object above, but you say it has 4 questions which is confusing to me as it only has two "question" objects. If you are counting each "question" object as two then just multiply by two the returned result of my function.